# Load XML into memory

Tags: java, xml, performance

I have an XML file that I need to read entirely, and I don't know what use (DOM, SAX or JAXB)
I have seen many things on internet but I'm still doubting....

As I need all the data which are in the file, it's a good idea to parse the file for create Java's objects like beans ? Because :

If I use SAX without using beans, I will have to read the file entirely at each time I need a data.
And if I use DOM without using beans, I will have to perform request at each time I need a data.

So, firstly, have you got the same opinion ?

Secondly, if I use beans, what do you preconize between DOM, SAX or JAXB and why ?

- I need to read my file entirely.
- I don't need to modify my file.
- My file is small (20Ko).

Answer (score 0):

you can use XSLT if you are working on same xml all the time.

the better way of doing it is by using jaxb. JAXB helps you in parsing the xml file by making beans,and if you are using eclipse its quite simple.

-create a jaxb project.
-add your xml to the source.
-right click xml.
-generate java class.

Comment: Hum ok, but use beans is a good or a bad way ?
Because XSLT requests are less performant than just get data from beans no ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this dynamically I recommend checking out:

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152

Then use Beans to store the data, as this is the purpose of using an Object Oriented language.

Comment: Really interesting, but at the end, with beans, DOM has same performance than SAX, because all the data are in memory no ?

And what don't you use JAXB ?

Answer (score 0):

If the XML represents one nice *usable* data model, go for [**JAXB** with annotations](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JAXB/article.html). Almost no overhead (no boiler plate code, no XSD or so).

Less developing effort than XPath or other XML techniques.

Comment: Ok I think it's the right solution, I have an XSD file, but it just precise the type, the length, and the occurs of element.

Comment: With an XSD one might generate the java bean classes. I find manual construction with annotations more to my liking, but take a look into JAXB.